# How can I open a .cbh databse

Tags: database, chessbase

On my old windows-pc I created a database of my games on fritz 11 which I then uploaded to googledrive. The database is a .cbh file. My old computer broke and I'd like to re-open this database. As I have a mac, I got my roommate to download chessbase reader and sent him the database, but when trying to open it the message appeared

"new-database.cbh is not a database".

Does anyone know why this might have happened? Can anyone suggest something?

Comment: [transformation ][1] has strong opinions about chessbase and claims to be an expert.  I will ask and see what he says.


  [1]: https://www.chess.com/forum/view/chess-equipment/chessbase-10-or-chessbase-reader-2013

Answer (score 3):

A .cbh file is not a complete database. A database in Chessbase format consists of multiple files.

To backup or transfer Chessbase databases between computers, you can either:

1. [Backup in Chessbase](http://en.chessbase.com/support-kb/content/details/318/Backups) to a .cbv file
2. [Save games in portable PGN](http://en.chessbase.com/support-kb/content/details/288/Saving%20Games%20in%20PGN)

Answer (score 1):

The file might be corrupted or maybe the chess reader your friend got is broken. You could try using a different reader. You could also ask your friend to re-download the file in case there was some downloading error.

I just read [this](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/convert-chessbase-format-to-pgn-on-linux?rq=1) about converting .cbh to another format and apparently [scidb](http://scidb.sourceforge.net/) can read .cbh. Maybe your friend could try using scidb to see if it opens in that.

Alternatively you might need to do something inside chessbase in which case I would not know what to recommend.

Answer (score 1):

cbh is a FILE created by ChessBase, a program used for replaying chess games; saves header information about played chess games; saved with several other files that together comprise the total database and must be copied with the other files in order for the database to function properly.

If you don't want to copy the CBH file and all corresponding files, you can bundle all of them together in a .CBV file using ChessBase or Fritz.

Looks like you uploaded the wrong file.  Should have used a CBV.

NOTE: You can open ChessBase databases using the free ChessBase Reader program.