# Is there a Windows based command line tool to convert cbh to pgn?

Tags: software, database

I see that there is code for an Android app available at https://code.google.com/p/cb2pgn/, but I wonder if anyone has taken the time to make a standalone .exe that does the job?

Comment: The code you quote was derived from ScidB. Yes, there is a windows version but probably not like a stand-alone exe.

Comment: There are some in-browser utilities, but no, I don't see any Windows executables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Chessbase format files to .pgn?](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/6442/how-to-convert-chessbase-format-files-to-pgn)

Answer (score 1):

If you have Chess Assistant (CA), it will do the conversion for you.  For example, within CA just right click game on the game and go to Edit --> Copy to Clipboard and pick pgn.