# Is there a way to convert a .cbh file to PGN without a GUI?

Tags: pgn, chessbase, python, scidb, uncbv

I want to convert a .cbh file to PGN (or whatever format meta information (elo, player, score, etc) from which I can eventually convert to dataframe/json/anything easy to work with).

The most popular solution is [Scidb](https://scidb.sourceforge.net), but I don't think you can use it in CLI, you have to use the GUI.

Comment: Very strongly related question - https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/9208/is-there-a-windows-based-command-line-tool-to-convert-cbh-to-pgn