# Read chessbase files (.cbv) on ios?

Tags: chessbase

Is there any ios app that can read .cbv files?

If not, how can I convert them to .pgn? I tried to follow [this post](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/13737/7002), but the output is "parse error" to chess viewer (developed by everyman chess).

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no such iOS app. Sorry.

Try the Chessbase Fritz to do the conversion.