# Convert ctg to abk

Tags: chessbase, fritz, arena

I have several databases (openings) in ctg format that I use with Fritz or with Chessbase. I would like to use them with Arena, which need abk format. Is the ctg to abk conversion possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert Chessbase format files to .pgn?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/6442/how-to-convert-chessbase-format-files-to-pgn)

Comment: I am looking for a "ctg --> abk" conversion. The question you are pointing to concerns a "ctg --> pgn" conversion. Unless there is a very easy way to convert pgn to abk, the question you point does not answer my question.

Comment: @Phonon By the way in the link you provide, files extensions (ctb, ctg, cto) of ChessBase books are not covered (using for instance ChessBase Reader as I did).

Answer (score 1):

I answered this question earlier on this site.  Is there some way to search?  The best I could say with my research is that there is a program being written to do it but it is not out yet.   And google says according to one source to do a double conversion such as with a program like fritz to change it going in and export it different coming back out.

Comment: There are plenty of search options; it’s actually easy yo view, say, only answers by a certain user.

Comment: how would you search for a specific question or topic ?

Comment: Depends; you can use tags and other filtering mechanisms, or just keywords. The “advanced search” button gives the best resource

Comment: okay.  for us old dinosaurs where is this search button.  i do not see anything looking like search on my screen whether button box icon or other.

Comment: Mobile or desktop? Near top of site on desktop: search bar. Should be. Mobile is a bit wonkier.

Comment: desktop.  are you saying i have to go somewhere else besides https://chess.stackexchange.com  ?  nevermind.  I finally see it.   it is hidden in the gray font on gray blackground and i missed it.  as my eye is drawn to the right with the bright number and other icons there.

Comment: @yobamamama Here is the list https://chess.stackexchange.com/users/20776/yobamamama?tab=answers of all your answers on the chess.stackexchange site. Which one does answer my question ?

Comment: I repeated the answer here.  So it would be that one.  There is a program yet to be released.  Else googling says to import and export in another program.

Comment: @yobamamama Could you please quote your sources in your answer ? Thx !

Comment: I did not document them for future use.  I found them to answer the question.

Comment: @yobamamama To resume : 1) you answered to a same question than mine earlier on this site and you cannot find it back (neither do I with all possible keywords using the search provide in the site + there's no answer of yours related to this in the complete list of you answers chess.stackexchange.com/users/20776/yobamamama?tab=answers) 2) You say having repeated this answer in the "answer" you gave to my question which is least to say vague 3) you pretend having found stuff on the internet but you are unable to provide clue or trace of it.

What should I conclude of all of this ?

Comment: @yobamamama Btw this post firmly contradicts what you pretend : https://rec.games.chess.computer.narkive.com/Fck6tlpD/reading-ctb-cto-ctg-files
and it contradicts it with a rationale.

Comment: your link 404 on my pc.  I gave my answer.  it is correct.  I stand by it.  You can conclude anything you want.

Comment: @yobamamama My link does not 404 on your pc ah ah. You are a liar, and anyone reading this would conclude the same. If you don't know something, it is not a problem. But if you pretend knowing it, having solution for it, when you haven't, and making everytone waste its time, it is pitiful. You won't get recognition this way.